# can i trigger event after receiving message on sqs without using any lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have tried to do some R&D but i couldn't find anything useful the only thing that i found is lambda functions is the only way. I want to write a simple application that execute when the  Simple Queue Service receive any message , but i couldn't find a way to do that till now, since i don't want to use lambda. for example if i receive some message on  Simple Queue Service  and while receiving  each messages i can trigger a event that is not lambda but instead of that any HTTP-request.

Comment: Check this out: https://cloudhut.io/connect-aws-api-gateway-to-sqs-923cf312bf78

Comment: actually what i looking is sqs connected  with any application but not aws service. like it can trigger a event which accept any HTTP request and execute accordingly. something like socket connection.

Comment: I think then you are looking for this: https://github.com/BBC/sqs-consumer

Comment: what you have shared is where api gateway is connected to sqs. api gateway is only pushing the data to sqs not receiving or fire any event after getting any data.

Comment: yet this is also a consumer. for this you have to deploy your application on some place?

Comment: yes... otherwise SQS has no interface to move messages via HTTP.  So you either need API Gateway, a lambda, some other AWS service or an application to consume SQS messages. So your best bet is to use a consumer library in a node app

Comment: and that node api might be running on ec2 right? which continuously monitoring each data on sqs  and trigger some event on the same. correct me if i'm wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I think your choices are:

- use lambda (which you said you didn't want to use, but its probably the best solution)
- use your own app running on ec2 or even on premise to consume the message and invoke the http endpoint
- use SNS instead of SQS for message delivery - SNS supports http endpoints.

> You can use Amazon SNS to send notification messages to one or more
>   HTTP or HTTPS endpoints. When you subscribe an endpoint to a topic,
>   you can publish a notification to the topic and Amazon SNS sends an
>   HTTP POST request delivering the contents of the notification to the
>   subscribed endpoint. When you subscribe the endpoint, you select
>   whether Amazon SNS uses HTTP or HTTPS to send the POST request to the
>   endpoint.

from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

Comment: for my own application first it has to poll every message from sqs and after that it will trigger some event right?

Comment: and i think SNS is also not a good solution because internally it is using SQS. so it just using the same thing having higher price.

Comment: @amitkumar not sure why you believe SNS is "basically internally" using SQS.  Yes, your application needs to poll SQS because that is the way SQS works -- consumers long-poll the queue, waiting for messages.  The SQS >> Lambda integration uses worker threads (running on a service provided/managed by Lambda) to poll the queue and then invoke the Lambda function when messages arrive.

Comment: @Micheal- i know the best solution is to use lambda. but the thing is i can use only one service of aws i:e; SQS. Now i have a app that will consumers long-poll the queue, waiting for messages. is it possible that the application can be independent from other aws services like ec2 or lambda?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your question is No, (until today)
Let me tell you the sineros i faced.In general Queue triggering lambda is widely used and for that u have to make sure about proper  concurrency (minimum 5) in place and also database I/O if u are performing and any DB calls . But I've a scenario where we cannot use "lambda as a triggering service"  as our DB is onprem "ORACLE" so the choices are .

1. Push to "SNS" and make http "what ever applies"(to a container we have custom Kubernetes routed through NLB ).Also make sure you push a batch of messages as it might make more http noise.

2.Poll the queue and perform the operations.

3. SQS triggering => Lambda and lambda invoking state machine (step functions)